# Complex layout with rows of information

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap - and I need to layout this:
[image]

It needs to be responsive.

Does this count as 'tabular data'? Should a table be used? How can we keep it on one line across all responsive widths and aligned correctly?

I have tried using responsive columns but it requires a lot of manual adjustment at each width and just doesn't seem elegant.

Am I missing an obvious solution here or is this inherently hard?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, for a responsive layout it's better to use a bootstrap `list-group` rather than a table. Each list group item should contain a `row` with `columns` in the required sizes.

I would advise against keeping it all on one line for a smart-phone size device though, as there's quite a lot of content to fit on. In this code the columns are stacked on xs devices.

Here's an example bootply: http://www.bootply.com/nVV0PvhNFC

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <p>Image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <p>Fund name</p>
          <p>Sector</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <p>Favourite</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <p>Read More</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks - why a list group out of interest? The problem here is similar to what I tried in that it needs a large amount of manual tweaking to make everything fit on one line at the 3 non mobile sizes. Huge amounts of work. I guess there's no way round that?

Comment: To clarify if I don't do that tweaking things don't line up well in the higher resolutions - there are random gaps etc.

Comment: Also - this list-group needs to occupy 10 columns from the main page - with an offset of 1 either side. Should i nest this within regular columns or is there a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In general the easiest way to obtain responsiveness is to use percentage value on width properties;
furthermore css [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) should be used to target certain displays or width
(using media queries you can create custom styles on specific situations);

an basically that's exactly the principle of the [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) (i mention it because I see that's how you've tagged your question);

If I was you, I'd use bootstrap `container` and `rows` and then customize the styles for content inside rows ( you could also use bootstrap's columns if it's convenient ....).

Comment: Customise the styles how exactly?